# Even rescue fails: "end kernel panic not syncing VFS unable to mount root"

Tags: boot, kernel, luks

I just upgraded my LTS to the latest (20.04 -> 22.04) and it failed on reboot. Even using the previous kernel, even in rescue mode it fails the same way.

I've had a similar problem long ago that involved booting from a LiveUSB and doing a chroot... but could anybody give me some pointers as to what to try ?

Complication: the partition is encrypted... (it doesn't reach the step where it asks for the passwd)

The last messages seen on screen are (somewhat simplified):

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "mapper/kubuntu--vg-root" or unknown block(0,0) error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU 0 PID 1 Comm swapper/0 not tainted 5.4.0-125-generic #141-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Hewlett...
Call trace: dump_stack/panic/mount_block_root/mount_root/prepare_namespace...
Kernel Offset...
End kernel panic - not syncing VFS Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Comment: I've seen a similar question here, can you check `/etc/crypttab` ? it should be `devicename_crypt UUID=..` , if so, you can edit `/etc/fstab` , replace kubuntu--vg-root with devicename_crypt and it should hopefully work, if you get weird errors, try to update grub from live usb

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427212/looking-for-wrong-encrypted-partition-on-boot?noredirect=1#comment2485414_1427212 attacked earlier and from a different angle...